# Run Console App in Azure - without WebJobs

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

So, as the title says, is there a way to run regular .Net FW Console Apps in Azure? 
For a little more info, what do I mean? I have a simple Console App that does something in infinite loop and checks some values for me, so nothing big. It also uses threading. 
Now, I would really like to avoid using WebJobs or Azure functions for this. 
Is there a way to do this? And if it is possible, how? 

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the two things that could really be of use for this scenario? If you do not want to use the advantages of azure what is the point of trying to run your workload there?

Comment: @PeterBons Hey.. Thanks for taking intereset. Let`s say that this is a research, I just want to know the alternatives. Pros and cons also. I mean I googled it a lot and all I see is usage of WebJobs and Azure functions. Are we limited to this only? Is there no other option?

Comment: Yes, try azure container instances (aci).

Comment: @PeterBons As far as I can tell, those are used per request, I cannot make it a long lasting background Console App. Did I get this right?

Comment: No, you can run them for as long as you need them, it is a pay-per-use model. Though if you're running them 24/7 then yes, there are better alternatives. I'd say use the azure price calculator and calculate the costs per service. You could use the answer below as input for the [calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/).

Comment: @PeterBons What would you suggest for a 24/7 running console app? Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Run it on Azure Pipelines: https://devsdaily.com/azure-devops-how-to-run-console-applications-on-azure-pipeline/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options (some of which you already mentioned) for running console apps in Azure:

- IaaS: run your own VM and execute your console app in it, simple and to the point
- Azure Container Instance
- Service Fabric
- Azure Batch: may require some rewrite as it's not really running console apps but tasks
- Azure WebJob
- Azure Function

The following link shows a flowchart for choosing the appropriate Azure service and may help you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree

Comment: hey.. ok, sure.. BUT, I would like to avoid running my own VM, for sure, I don't want entire VM to run one small app. I just looked at Azure Container Instance, so as far as I read, these are not prefered to be used for a long running process. Also, maybe I am mistaken, but it seems like these can't run in background.

Comment: Is there a way for me to deploy my console app somewhere, in Azure, and let it work non-stop in the background? And still keep it simple, without VM`s and stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Azure Batch Service to run several lonng running tasks in one console app.I used command line parameters to decide which function to run.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;

namespace MyConsoleAppRunningAsJobInAzureBatchService
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Missing parameter... Exit program.");
                return 1;
            }

            switch (args[0].ToString())
            {
                case "-task1":
                    RunLongRunningTask1();
                    break;
                case "-task2":
                    RunLongRunningTask2();
                    break;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        private static void RunLongRunningTask1()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // put your code here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This concept was very stable, some jobs ran for several days.

The above is the most simple part. I found it difficult to find out how to create a Batch Service Job. This is possible by using Batch.NET library
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-run-dotnet

I have some code example for that, just let me know if you want to follow this path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can you please improve your answer by adding related command or code.

Comment: I have added code example for the console application.

Comment: I want to mention Batch Servies are 'pay as you', so it is cheaper to run shorter tasks.